# How does People Pane in Outlook 2010 show pictures?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, pictures

We've just started using Outlook 2010 in my organization.

When I send an email from my account (`user@organization.com`) to a different account, in let's say Hotmail:

If the person is using Outlook 2010 to get Hotmail mails, will it be possible for him to see the picture of people in `TO` and `CC`? even if he's not part of the organization?

Answer (score 1):

Outlook 2010 does not automatically send your contact information in emails you send.

Pictures seen when hovering over names in the `To` and `CC` are only seen if a picture is available in that contact profile created by the recipient. If the person receiving your email does not have you in their contacts, they won't see anything.

You can send them your `Business Card` so they have you information correct and with an image. Here is a tutorial on how to make and use them business cards - [Use electronic business cards in Outlook 2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/use-electronic-business-cards-in-outlook-2010-RZ102019638.aspx)